# Is there a way to send a calendar event via UIActivityViewController?

Tags: objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller, ekevent

The title pretty much says it all. What follows is my best guess, but the event just doesn't appear at all.

```
NSArray *items = @[string, URL, (EKEvent *)[self createCalendarEvent]];
UIActivityViewController* activity = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:activities];
[self presentViewController:activity animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this? Or do I have to create an ics file and send that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**UIActivityViewController**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller):

> The system provides several **standard services**, such as copying items
>   to the pasteboard, posting content to social media sites, sending
>   items via email or SMS, and more.
>
> *Apps can also define custom services*.

It's not (yet) possible to share an `EKEvent-object` nor its parent `EKCalendarItem` as none of the **standard services** provide a way to [interact with this type of activity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivity/1620677-canperform).

You should indeed create an `.ics-file` to share your event. It's a bit strange that iOS doesn't convert the object by itself as it do this for strings (into .txt-files).

You could however [fill in a request](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) to get this option.